# Why do I always get blocked by CORS while using location.href

Tags: javascript, cors

I have been having a strange error while trying to redirect from my domain to another domain. This is what am trying to do:

```
location.href="https://paystack.com/secure/xxx"
```

This is error am getting:

```
Failed to load https://paystack.com/secure/xxx: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:59610' is therefore not allowed access
```

What can I do to get pass this?

Comment: why are you trying to change the url like that? it seems an odd thing to do

Comment: The code in your question would not trigger a CORS issue. Something else is causing this problem. Nothing anyone here can do unless your identify that problem.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon How best can I do it

Comment: by not doing it at all? why do you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: @Liam I thought that too, but [it seems it can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Comment: IIRC, CORS preflight requests are only sent if HTTP headers or POST parameters are sent to the URL. You would have to check the request in browser debugger's network tab to find which headers or parameters are sent. Depending on your finding, we may be able to tell you how to remove these headers or parameters.

Answer (score -4):

I finally got it working. 
This is what I did

```
window.location.replace('domain');
window.location.href ='domain'
```

Comment: The first line doesn't do anything.